# How to get call history, call receiver/sender name from iPhone in Objective C?

Tags: iphone

I am to work on an application, where I'll have to fetch details of the call history of the last calls in the iPhone, name of the person who made a call or to whom the call is made.

My problem is I found so many applications providing such details,but am not able to get any source code or some solution pertaining to this.

Comment: Did you find examples of apps that do it in the App Store? Or someplace like Cydia?

Comment: ya,i saw some examples,but no code is available for the same so cant get any idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call history is stored in `call_history.db`, this db is not accessible.

Apple restricts call log usage, so you can't access/change the mode like this unless it is a jail-broken iPhone.

Comment: i guess i was knowing it,anyways,is it possible to atleast find name of the person made/receive a call as well as email sender/receiver?

Comment: Ur code wont show any error but u that db is locked one.. u cant access anythng

Answer (score 1):

There is no legal way to accomplish this and still be able to distribute via the App Store.